# String variable unrecognized in Jquery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/)
to customize my checkboxes. In the documentation they suggest using:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

So in my case I have multiple checkboxes so I did this:

```
var name = '"' + "[name='my-checkbox" + records[i].id + "']" + '"';
$(name).bootstrapSwitch();
```

But I get an error: Unrecognized expression: "[name='my-checkbox1']"

Comment: Use only `"[name='my-checkbox" + records[i].id + "']"`, no need of other extra quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extra `"`

```
var name = '[name="my-checkbox' + records[i].id + '"]';
```

***`Example`***

```js
var records = [
  {id: '-one'},
  {id: '-two'}
];

var name;

for (var i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
  name = '[name="my-checkbox' + records[i].id + '"]';
  console.log($(name));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="my-checkbox-one" type="checkbox">
<input name="my-checkbox-two" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need that much coding... If you add a class to you checkbox `<input name="my-checkbox" class="nice-switch" type="checkbox">`you can then activate the switch using `$(".nice-switch").bootstrapSwitch();`